# Why does a class have the attributes of its metaclass?

Tags: python, subclass, metaclass

I have a metaclass like this

```
class UpperMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        uppercase_attr = {}
        for name, val in dct.items():
            if not name.startswith('__'):
                uppercase_attr[name.upper()] = val
            else:
                uppercase_attr[name] = val

        return super(UpperMeta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, uppercase_attr)

    def echo(cls):
        return 'echo'

class B(object):
    __metaclass__ = UpperMeta

assert hasattr(B, 'echo')
assert B.echo() == 'echo'
assert not issubclass(B, UpperMeta)
```

My question is:

1. Why does class `B` have an `echo`-method? If `B` is not a subclass of `UpperMeta`, it should not have the `echo` attr?
2. Which attributes does a class get from a metaclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `class` object `B` is of `type` `UpperMeta`.

This has the consequence that all classmethods of `UpperMeta` are available on the class `B`. The attribute is not on the class `B`, but gets proxied from `B`'s class(`B` is the class, not an instance of `B`)

```
>>> print dir(B)
# General lack of echo()
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

It's here:

```
>>> print dir(B.__class__)
['__abstractmethods__', '__base__',  ..., 'echo', 'mro']
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors):

> The default behavior for attribute access is to get, set, or delete
>   the attribute from an object’s dictionary. For instance, a.x has a
>   lookup chain starting with a.**dict**['x'], then
>   type(a).**dict**['x'], and continuing through the base classes of
>   type(a) excluding metaclasses.

---

This is a little confusing towards the end *"...excluding metaclasses.."*, which really means the metaclasses of type(a), therefore saying that if your metaclass `UpperMeta` has a metaclass `TopMeta` and `TopMeta` defines `sos()`, that one won't be looked up:

```
class TopMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        uppercase_attr = {}
        for name, val in dct.items():
            if not name.startswith('__'):
                uppercase_attr[name.upper()] = val
            else:
                uppercase_attr[name] = val

        return super(TopMeta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, uppercase_attr)

    def sos(cls):
        return 'sos'

class UpperMeta(type):
    __metaclass__ = TopMeta
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        uppercase_attr = {}
        for name, val in dct.items():
            if not name.startswith('__'):
                uppercase_attr[name.upper()] = val
            else:
                uppercase_attr[name] = val

        return super(UpperMeta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, uppercase_attr)

class B(object):
    __metaclass__ = UpperMeta

assert not hasattr(B, 'sos')
```

The only talk that ever explained metaclasses properly: [*David Beazley - Python 3 Metaprogramming*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPiWg5jSoZI). You only have the first 80 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

> why class B have method of echo, B is not subclass of UpperMeta, it
>   should not have echo attr?

If you look at [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) or [Customizing class creation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation), you see that (quotes from python docs)

> if `__metaclass__` is defined then the callable assigned to it will be
>   called instead of type().

[`type()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type)

> is essentially a dynamic form of the class statement. The name string
>   is the class name and becomes the `__name__` attribute; the bases
>   tuple itemizes the base classes and becomes the `__bases__` attribute;
>   and the dict dictionary is the namespace containing definitions for
>   class body and becomes the `__dict__` attribute. For example, the
>   following two statements create identical type objects:
>
> ```
> >>> class X(object):
> ...     a = 1
> ...
> >>> X = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))
> ```

This is, it is "just like" class extension. This also answers

> What attribute class get from metaclass?

Pretty much everything.

Please also [be aware that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/1587329)

> If you wonder whether you need them, you don't (the people who
>   actually need them know with certainty that they need them, and don't
>   need an explanation about why).

yet in the [video posted by @Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33473559/1587329), he says

> Q: Can you have too much of [metaprogramming]
>   A: No

So he thinks it important enough to learn.

Comment: I couldn't find the quote! Thanks.

Comment: @Sebastian: You are welcome. It is right after the beginning. Thank you for the video.